# Is it faster to query a List<T> or database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, performance, linq

I have recently had several situations where I need different data from the same table. One example is where I would loop through each "delivery driver" and generate a printable PDF file for each customer they are to deliver to.

In this situation, I pulled all customers and stored them into

```
List<Customer> AllCustomersList = customers.GetAllCustomers();
```

As I looped through the delivery drivers, I'd do something like this:

```
List<Customer> DeliveryCustomers = AllCustomersList.Where(a => a.DeliveryDriverID == DriverID);
```

My question: Is the way I'm doing it by querying the List object faster than querying the database each time for customer records associated with the delivery driver?

Comment: I cannot conceive a way that pulling data from the database would be better then doing everything in memory like you are currently doing it...  The only thing I can think to do is make sure you are not pulling MORE data then you are going to use...

Comment: Querying a list should be much, much faster since it would be stored in memory.

Comment: At what point will it become too much data to put into the list and need to use the database?

Comment: @xbonez. That isn't true. DB are built for filtering, with large amount of data, you use DB, not in memory.

Comment: @xbonez - while you are right for smaller sets of data, for very large sets (maybe 10s or 100s of thousands, maybe millions, maybe more), the DB becomes more efficient due primarily to indexing and the organization of the set of data in memory. Of course if the DB can keep the entire dataset in memory, it will be more efficient than on disk.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There isn't an accurate number for amount of rows that if you pass it you should query the DB instead in in-memory `List<T>`

But the rule of thumb is, DB are designed to work with large amount of data and they have optimization "mechanisms"  while in in-memory there aren't such things.

So you will need to benchmark it to see if the round-trip to DB is worth it for that amount of rows **for each time it's important to you**

*"We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: **premature 
optimization is the root of all evil**"*

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding round trips to DB is one of the major rules regarding database performance tuning, especially when the DB is located on network and has multiple users accessing it.

From the other point of view bringing large result sets into memory like you customers data looks to be, is not efficient and probably not faster than traveling to DB when you need them.

A good use of in memory collections to avoid round trips is for your look up tables (i.e. customer categories, customer regions, etc), which don't change often. That way you avoid joins in your main customer select query making it even faster.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [Redis](http://redis.io/) ? , It's an in memory database and it's very fast.